# Scrollable card content with Vuetify

Tags: css, vuejs2, flexbox, vuetify.js

Hello I am trying to create scrollable content in card with flex util classes and components of Vuetify but I am unsuccessful. He is my last version of code which I tried:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/sharp-kilby-g3e4t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

This is my expectation is this:

[image]

I found some samples with pure flex but I am not able did it with Vuetify? Can you help me edit codesandbox to make it working? Thank you.

Comment: the items in your codesandbox are the lines or intended to be the scrollable content?

Comment: @Mech thank you for effort, it should be like in sketch, so it will be card fit in page container under app bar, and in card will be some header, or search input, and below scrollable content. It will be vuetify's list component like in demo in codesandbox.

Comment: @DenisStephanov let's fix it, can you ping me on skype: syed_haroon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is much related to CSS than `Vuetify`, so let me explain you how you can fix it. Say that your markups render in the browser like below `html`, either style `v-card__text` or add your custom class `my-list`, if you are using `v-card__text` to style then make sure to add scoped to `style` tag in your component else this will effect entire project.

```
<div class="v-card v-sheet theme--light">
  <div class="v-card__title">You Title goes here</div>
  <div class="v-card__text my-list">
    <ul>
      <li>Text</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style scoped>
  .my-list {
    // For eg. here 200px is MainNavBar + TitleBar and some padding/margins
    // keep on increasing height if you have more items placed above the v-card
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the height to the `v-list` then make it scrollable using `overflow-y: scroll;`

```html
<!-- Set height to your `<v-list>` and add `overflow-y: scroll` -->
<v-list style="height: 250px; overflow-y: scroll">
  <v-list-item-group color="primary">
    <v-list-item v-for="(n) in 100" :key="n">
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>Item {{ n }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>
```

I've edited your code and here is a working example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wildflower-8rfl4?file=/src/App.vue).

Here is a sample output of what you want based on your sketch.
[image]

Comment: I asked how to did in flexbox. If I did it with fixed height I lost responsivity. But thank you for efort

Answer (score 2):

Uses the component=`v-virtual-scroll` built in **Vuetify** will be one solution.

for example:

```
        <v-card class="flex-grow-0">
          <v-virtual-scroll
            :items="Array.from({length: 100}).map((_, index) => index)"
            :item-height="50"
            height="300"
          >
            <template v-slot="{ item }">
              <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title>Item {{ item }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </template>
          </v-virtual-scroll>
        </v-card>
```

[Updated CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-stonebraker-ss67v)